# How to print the nodes from XMLNodeList

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming. I am trying to parse an XML document and print the values on console. My program is compiling without errors but I am not getting the desired result.

Here is the Code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\hsyed\\Documents\\XMLParser\\Example.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "Identifier");
XmlNodeList node = doc.SelectNodes("//root/ab:Identity/Refrences/Reference/Value/text()", nsmgr);

String s= node.ToString();
System.Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.Read();
```

The XML File

```
    <Attributes>

        <Attribute Name="StudentFirstName" Tag="B"/>

    </Attributes>
</Metadata>
<Identities>
<Identity Identifier="00002C8DGPDDTZ5D" CDate="2013-02-07">
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Value>A^S2513.268898|B^JOHN</Value>
            <Traces/>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Value>A^S2613.269022|B^JOHN</Value>
            <Traces/>
        </Reference>
    </References>
</Identity>
<Identity Identifier="000388MRUO7TRSBH" CDate="2013-02-07">
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Value>A^S2513.285402|B^Doe</Value>
            <Traces/>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Value>A^S2613.285476|B^Doe</Value>
            <Traces/>
        </Reference>
    </References>
</Identity>
```

I want to get the information in the Value field.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not see the entire xml but your xpath seems wrong. you have "//root/ab:Identity/Refrences/Reference/Value/text()" instead of "//root/Identity/Refrences/Reference/Value/text()". Once you get the right list you need to iterate list and then print out.

Comment: You mean something like this  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load("C:\\Users\\hsyed\\Documents\\XMLParser\\Example.xml");
                XmlNodeList node = doc.SelectNodes("//root/Identities/Identity/Refrences/Reference/Value/text()");
                for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(node.ToString);

                }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\hsyed\\Documents\\XMLParser\\Example.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//root/Identities/Identity/Refrences/Reference/Value/text()");

foreach (XmlNode xn in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xn.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is there really no override of `<any collection>.ToString()` in C#, comparable to [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) in Java?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that piggybacks on LINQ:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("whatever path to xml");

var nodes = doc
    .SelectNodes("xpath query goes here")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    // optionally, convert to a list
    .ToList();

// Outputs something like: 
//   System.Collection.Generic.List`1[[System.Xml.XmlNode, ...]]
Console.WriteLine(nodes.GetType().FullName);
```